# how do i input multiple pieces data into a joined database by has_and_belongs_to_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i am currently building a contractor system for my company and i have decided to use devise for the signup system. Each contractor can have many tools assigned to them and vice versa. in my sign up form i have used this

```
 <% for tool in Tool.all %>
                        <div>
                            <%= check_box_tag "user[tool_ids]", tool.id, @user.tools.include?(tool.id) %>
                            <%= tool.name %>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>

              </div>
```

which on the users sign up form allows me to assine one tool to a user but then nothing.

using the sign up form how can i allow the users to add in as many tools as they wish on signup and assign them to that table

so in theroy i want to do

```
@user.tools << Tool.find(1)
@user.tools << Tool.find(2)
@user.tools << Tool.find(3)
@user.tools << Tool.find(4)
```

but within the signup process.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Here's one way: User accepts_nested_attributes_for :some_join_objects (with a reject_if argument) and then in your user controller's new action build as many associated join objects for user as you have tools. That will automatically populate your join objects into the form if you use a combination of form_for user, and fields_for :some_join_objects. And then reject_if some selectable attribute on the join object is false.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is sending over params that look like this (including other data which you haven't shown, perhaps):

```
{
  user: {
    tool_ids: []
  }
}
```

In the controller, the `tool_ids` array will only include those that were checked. So you can do something like this:

```
# create join records
params[:user][:tool_ids].each do |tool_id|
  UsersTools.create(tool_id: tool_id, user_id: @user.id)
end

# reload the in-memory user object to reflect the db
# no need to do this if you're redirecting
@user.reload
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found a nice way of doing this

in your form use this instead which then takes in arrays.

```
 <% for tool in Tool.all %>
                        <div>
                            <%= check_box_tag "user[tool_ids][]", tool.id, @user.tools.include?(tool.id) %>
                            <%= tool.name %>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>

              </div>
```

you will then need to do into your application controller and allow strong parameters for devise to allow arrays for the specific field

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
    user_params.permit({ tool_ids: [] },:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```